# How to address the response data correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In my authentication service, I need to store the id of the authenticated user. I also need to store the access token and the username. Both (token and username) are stored correctly(Key and Value) in the storage when I go to the application tab of my dev tool. But my user_id is either the value undefined when using this code `this.storage.set(USER_ID, res['user_id']);` or I get as a value `NaN` when I first try to convert it into a number(which is probably necessary since user_id is a number). This would be this version `this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.validateId(res['user_id']));` 
For `console.log('my user: ', this.user);` I get this data: `my user:  {token_type: "access", exp: 123 , user_id: 13}`

What am I doing wrong? Since the user_id is a number it should work!

```
const TOKEN_KEY = 'access_token'; // this is stored
export const USERNAME_KEY = 'username_key'; // this is stored
export const USER_ID = 'user_id'; // this isn't stored
...
user = null;
authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private storage: Storage, private helper: JwtHelperService,
              private plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });
   }

 checkToken() {
       this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(access => {
           if (access) {
               this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(access);
               this.authenticationState.next(true);
           }
       });
   }

  validateId(user_id: any): number {
    return parseInt(user_id);
}

   apilogin(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/`, { username, password })
    .pipe(
        tap(res => {
            this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, res['access']); // this is stored
            this.storage.set(USERNAME_KEY, username); // this is stored
            this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.validateId(res['user_id'])); // this isn't stored
            this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
            console.log('my user: ', this.user);
            this.authenticationState.next(true);
        }),
        catchError(e => {
            this.showAlert('Oops smth went wrong!');
            throw new Error(e);
        }));
}
```

Comment: If you console.log(res) what does it output? It seems thet response does not have a 'user_id' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
```

set this data in this.user

```
{token_type: "access", exp: 123 , user_id: 13}
```

You can use user_id attribute com this.user, not from res

```
this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']);
this.storage.set(USER_ID, this.user['user_id']);
```